# Fitting new data points into existing clusters

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, prediction, hierarchical-clustering

This is my first attempt on clustering!

I have a situation where I need to fit my test data set into the existing clusters that I have already built using my train dataset and I have got neat 6 clusters using the HAC method. Now I want to fit the new test dataframe on the same HAC method that I have used. How I can I do that?

My code is as follows :

```
 import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
 from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
 import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc
 plt.figure(figsize =(15, 15)) 
 plt.title('Visualising the data') 
 Dendrogram = shc.dendrogram((shc.linkage(df_pca_reduced, method ='ward')))
 # import hierarchical clustering libraries

 # create clusters
 hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=6, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'ward')
 # save clusters for chart
 y_hc = hc.fit_predict(df_pca_reduced)
 hiersclus_frame = pd.DataFrame(df1)
 hiersclus_frame['cluster'] = y_hc
```

df_pca_reduced is the dataset that I have achieved after perfroming the PCA.

Now my clusters are stored in column cluster within df1.

The test dataset is "df" on which I want to run the same fit_predcit function to cluster this dataframe as well to get a similar cluster column on the df dataframe as well.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: `hc.predict(new_df_pca_reduced`?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: I did not understand your comment. Should I scale my test data and do a pca to create a new reduced data set called new_df_pca_reduced and then use hc.predict(new_df_pca_reduced? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. If you run PCA on your data prior to `AgglomerativeClustering` as you show in `hc.fit_predict(df_pca_reduced)` you should follow the same data preprocessing pipeline on test data and do `hc.predict(new_df_pca_reduced)`

Comment: Alright. let me do that! Thanks for this.

Comment: Do not forget to use the same PCAs for test, which you calculated for your train data...

Comment: You mean that if I have used pca = PCA(n_components=20) principalComponents = pca1.fit_transform(df1) for the train dataset , then I should be using the same principalComponents for my new train dataset as well? I was changing the instance for the test dataset to pca1, is that incorrect?

Comment: Assuming `pca1` is the previously instantiated (and fitted using the training data set) `PCA` instance, you would call `new_df_pca_reduced = pca1.transform(new_df)`.

Comment: got it!! Thanks!